# Can object detection be treated as an unbalanced classification

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

In the object detection problem, the background class seems to dominate the training data, since there are much more background samples than object samples.
So, can we treat object detection problem as an unbalanced classification problem? 
The fraud/intrusion detection seems to be widely treated as unbalanced classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your method for learning the object. The answer would be different in each of the following cases:

- The training set contains cut-outs of the object, with a plain (black or white) background. In this case, it would be unbalanced in favour of the object.
- The training set contains natural images with several instances of the object to be detected, and the model is learned in an unsupervised manner. In this case, the balance would depend on the consistency of the background.
- The training set contains cut-outs of several objects, to create a multiple-class object detector. In this case, the balance is distributed among a number of classes.

So I can't really think of a single standard conclusion for your question.